# iOS CocoaPods - how to find out available versions of a specific pod, not cocoapods itself?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dependency-management

I'm trying to revert to a previous version of a specific pod, but cant easily find a command for listing all versions I can revert to. Let's say I have:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3.0'
```

**How can I learn what versions of a specific cocoapod (ex: AFNetworking) I can install?** I want to see if it has 2.3.1, 2.3.5, 2.4.1, etc.

PS. Google is overflowing with questions about how to check for the version of cocoapods itself, but I'm asking about version history of  specific pods avaialable through that framework.

Comment: find the GitHub repo and look at their version tags

Comment: There' is a "versions" dropdown on top when viewing this page http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/3.1.0/

Comment: Haha, yeah, I just spent too much time with google, and it is indeed overflowing with questions about how to check for the version of cocoapods itself, so couldn't find the answer with even my "clever" google searches. Thanks to SO search, found your post!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
pod search afnetworking
```

Using above command brings up all info related to that pod (If exists)

Following is the output you get when you fire above command

> AFNetworking (3.1.0)    A delightful iOS and OS X networking
>   framework.    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
>      - Homepage: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking
>      - Source:   https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git
>      - Versions: 3.1.0, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 3.0.0-beta.3,
>      3.0.0-beta.2, 3.0.0-beta.1, 2.6.3, 2.6.2, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.5.4, 2.5.3, 2.5.2,
>      2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0,
>      2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.0-RC3, 2.0.0-RC2, 2.0.0-RC1, 1.3.4,
>      1.3.3, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0, 1.0RC3, 1.0RC2,
>      1.0RC1, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.7.0, 0.5.1 [master repo]
>      - Subspecs:
>        - AFNetworking/Serialization (3.1.0)
>        - AFNetworking/Security (3.1.0)
>        - AFNetworking/Reachability (3.1.0)
>        - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (3.1.0)
>        - AFNetworking/UIKit (3.1.0)

It has other info as well but you do get version info.

Answer (score 41):

To extend on the answer from Bhumit...

Use this for faster searching (searches only pod names, same result details)

`pod search afnetworking --simple`